# How to scan pandas row for first non-zero value and create new column with numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data set like the below:

```
+---+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|   | dc(uid): interaction_single_message_ | dc(uid): interaction_single_message_1 | dc(uid): interaction_yes |
+---+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 0 |                                    0 |                                     0 |                    89884 |
| 1 |                                    0 |                                    29 |                        0 |
| 2 |                                    0 |                                   239 |                      239 |
| 3 |                                  324 |                                     0 |                        0 |
| 4 |                                12021 |                                     0 |                    12021 |
+---+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

How can I go row by row and pick the first number that is encountered and add it to a new column at the same index.  If there are multiple numbers in a row, they will always be the same, which is why I am asking for the first encountered number.

The ideal output would be something like this:

```
+---+-------+
|   | nums  |
+---+-------+
| 0 | 89884 |
| 1 |    29 |
| 2 |   239 |
| 3 |   324 |
| 4 | 12021 |
+---+-------+
```

Would I be using groupby.unique() to do this?

Comment: does it have to be the first value? In your sample df all present values are the same so this would work: `df[df>0].mean(axis=1)`

Comment: Nope! it can be any value because they are all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample df, so long as all the present values are the same then the following would work, we use a boolean condition to mask out the `0` values and then call [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html#pandas.DataFrame.mean) and pass param `axis=1` to calculate the mean row-wise:

```
In [24]:

df[df>0].mean(axis=1)
Out[24]:
0    89884
1       29
2      239
3      324
4    12021
dtype: float64
```